# MVC Navigating through multiple associated models in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a CalendarioJuego  model that has a foreign key of the FechaPartido model and in turn this has a foreign key of the Temporada model. How can I access the attribute "Nombre" of the Temporada model from the CalendarioJuegoViewModel model to be able to display the associated details in a Index view and not showing just the Ids. How can I do that?

**CalendarioJuego** Model in API

```
public partial class CalendarioJuego
{
    public int CalJuegoId { get; set; }

    public int? CalFechaPartido { get; set; }

    public int? CalEquipoLocal { get; set; }

    public int? CalEquipoVisitante { get; set; }

    public virtual Equipo? CalEquipoLocalNavigation { get; set; } 

    public virtual Equipo? CalEquipoVisitanteNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual FechaPartido? CalFechaPartidoNavigation { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Partido> Partidos { get; set; } = new List<Partido>();
}
```

**CalendarioJuego** MVC consumer

```
    public class CalendarioJuego
    {
        [DisplayName("Id")]
        public int CalJuegoId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Equipo Local")]
        public int CalEquipoLocal { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Equipo Visitante")]
        public int CalEquipoVisitante { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Fecha de partido")]
        public int CalFechaPartido { get; set; }
    }
```

**CalendarioJuegoViewModel**

```
    public class CalendarioJuegoViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Id")]
        public int CalJuegoId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Fecha de partido")]
        public DateTime CalFechaPartido { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Equipo Local")]
        public string CalEquipoLocal { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Equipo visitante")]
        public string CalEquipoVisitante { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Hora")]
        public TimeSpan FecHora { get; set; }

    }
```

**FechaPartido** MVC consumer

```
    public class FechaPartido
    {
        public int FecId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Fecha de partido")]
        public DateTime FecFechaPartido { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Temporada")]
        public int FecTemporada { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Hora")]
        public TimeSpan FecHora { get; set; }
    }
```

**FechaPartidoViewModel** MVC consumer

```
    public class FechaPartido
    {
      public int FecId { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Fecha de partido")]
      public DateTime FecFechaPartido { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Temporada")]
      public string FecTemporada { get; set; }
      [DisplayName("Hora")]
      public TimeSpan FecHora { get; set; }
    }
```

**Temporada** MVC consumer

```
    public class FechaPartido
    {
        [DisplayName("Id")]
        public int TemId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Nombre")]
        public string TemNombre { get; set; } = null!;
        [DisplayName("Fecha de inicio")]
        public DateTime TemFecInicio { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Fecha de termino")]
        public DateTime TemFecFinal { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

**CalendarioJuegoController** MVC consumer

```
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           string baseApiUrl = _configuration.GetSection("LigaDominicanaApi").Value!;
           List<CalendarioJuego> calendarioJuegos = new List<CalendarioJuego>();
           List<FechaPartido> fechapartidos = new List<FechaPartido>();
           List<Equipo> equipos = new List<Equipo>();

           List<CalendarioJuegoViewModel> calendarioJuegoViewModel = new List<CalendarioJuegoViewModel>();
           

           string jsonCalendarioJuegosResponse = httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{baseApiUrl}/calendariojuegos").Result;
           calendarioJuegos = string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonCalendarioJuegosResponse) ? calendarioJuegos : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarioJuego>>(jsonCalendarioJuegosResponse)!;


           string jsonfechapartidosResponse = httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{baseApiUrl}/fechapartidos").Result;
           fechapartidos = string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonfechapartidosResponse) ? fechapartidos : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FechaPartido>>(jsonfechapartidosResponse)!;

           string jsonEquiposResponse = httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{baseApiUrl}/equipos").Result;
           equipos = string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonEquiposResponse) ? equipos : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Equipo>>(jsonEquiposResponse)!;


           foreach (CalendarioJuego juego in calendarioJuegos)
           {
               CalendarioJuegoViewModel customCalendarioJuego = new CalendarioJuegoViewModel()
               {

                   CalJuegoId = juego.CalJuegoId,
                   CalEquipoLocal = equipos.Where(e => juego.CalEquipoLocal == e.EqId).Select(e => e.EqNombre).FirstOrDefault()!,
                   CalEquipoVisitante = equipos.Where(e => juego.CalEquipoVisitante == e.EqId).Select(e => e.EqNombre).FirstOrDefault()!,
                   CalFechaPartido = fechapartidos.Where(e => juego.CalFechaPartido == e.FecId).Select(e => e.FecFechaPartido).FirstOrDefault()!,
                   FecHora = fechapartidos.Where(e => juego.CalFechaPartido == e.FecId).Select(e => e.FecHora).FirstOrDefault()!,

               };
               calendarioJuegoViewModel.Add(customCalendarioJuego);
           };


           return View(calendarioJuegoViewModel);
       }
```

How can I access the attribute "Nombre" of the Temporada model from the CalendarioJuegoViewModel model to be able to display the associated details in a Index view and not showing just the Ids. How can I do that?